# How to index parameters when formatting a string in Go

Tags: go, gofmt

Let's say I have a string `"Hello %s. How are you %s"` and I want to put the same string in both of `%s`. The obvious option is to use:

```
fmt.Printf("Hello %s. How are you %s", "KK", "KK") // returns "Hello KK. How are you KK"
```

is there a way to index the parameters so that I don't have to repeat `"KK"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it. The syntax is as follows:

```
fmt.Printf("Hello %[1]s. How are you %[1]s", "KK") // returns "Hello KK. How are you KK"
```

where `%[1]s` represents the first parameter after the string that is being formatted. You can also do something like this:

```
fmt.Printf("Hello %[1]s. How are you %[1]s. Where are you %[2]s", "KK", "today") // returns "Hello KK. How are you KK. Where are you today"
```